# Is android:id specific to xml file or the whole project?

Tags: android

Is the android:id="@+id/somevalue" specific to the xml file in which it is defined, or the whole android project?

If it is project-wide, it seems like I have a lot of id's to come up for text fields. For example I have to name my "title" field like "title1" and "title2" etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are unique on the whole project but can be used on different contexts. The reason is fairly simple: there will be just one `R.id.name_of_id` variable, though, they cannot be reference from anywhere. I mean, if you have and ID called `@+id/my_id` which is on the `my_layout.xml` file, you cannot use it unless you are currently working with `my_layout.xml` implicitly or explicitly. Implicity by using `findViewById` after a `setContentView(R.layout.my_layout.xml)` call (from the activity), or explicity by using it from an object (for instance, when you 'inflate' a layout and assign it to a `View` object you can do `object.findViewById()`).